# Can tubes be used in tubeless rims as well as tires?

Tags: tire, tubeless

I've gotten a bike with very nice tubeless wheels, however I have little experience with fixing or replacing tubeless tires/wheels. I would much prefer to be able to put a regular mountain bike tube in the tire and rim without problems or much hassle.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

Yes - take off the tire and the tubeless valve, clean up the rim, put on some new rim tape and then install a tube + tire.

If you're running tubeless and you have a failure, you can always just pop a tube in and continue your ride. And tubeless has its advantages (lower pressures since you can avoid pinch flats), so you may want to embrace it.

Comment: Do you know if there are any tubeless rim standards that are not compatible with clincher tires?

Comment: There aren't any, to my knowledge.

Comment: If the rim is tubeless then a rim tape is redundant.

Comment: If its truly a tubeless rim, yes. If its one of those which is marketed as "tubeless ready", possibly not.

Comment: It should be noted that, in theory, a tube-type tire needs to "breathe" -- air needs to be able to get into and out of the space between tube and tire/rim.  If this is really necessary on a bike tire (I have no idea) then presumably it could be facilitated by replacing the airtight rim strip with one that's a hair leaky.